# Why am I getting errors with Selenium XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to access all instances of a piece of text I can find on a website.

```
    rows = waitForAllElementsToLoad(By.XPATH, "//td[contains(.,'Jones']")
```

```
def waitForAllElementsToLoad(bySelector, name):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((bySelector, name))
        )
        print("HW")
        return element
    except:
        driver.quit()
        print("ERROR!1!")
        return
```

For some reason my WebDriverWait isn't working and it throws an error which triggers the except. I have everything imported, and I typed in the xpath onto google chrome inspect and that also works. Can someone tell me if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: except Exception as e:print(str(e))  check it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure the xpath is correct? As you have typed it here, you are missing a closing parenthesis for your contains clause.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Here is the error shown after I added my missing parenthesis

`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator`

Comment: @JD308 Thank you for noticing that, I double checked my code and I fixed it, but I am still getting the same error as the commented above